# How to hide all li except first two in one list, and third and fourth in another?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me how to hide all li expect first two li ? in secnd case I want to hide all li expect show 3 and 4 li on buttn click
here is my code

https://jsbin.com/damolibule/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function() {
  $('#id_show12').click(function() {
    $('.show12').not(":nth-child(2)").css("display", "none"); 
  })

  $('#id_show34').click(function() {
    $('.show34').not(":nth-child(5)").css("display", "none");  
  })
})
```

Expected output: when first button click it shows `1` and `2` only. If user clicks on second button it show `3` and `4`.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. The OP has shown effort at solving the problem, and provided all necessary code. This is a lot better than most questions we see.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you have any idea

Comment: Not sure what you mean - I already added an answer

Comment: no it is deleted

Comment: No it's not...? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44922388/519413

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show only the first two `li` you can use `:gt(1)` to get all the following `li`, then `hide()` them,

To show only the third and fourth `li` you can use `not()` in combination with `:eq(2)` and `:eq(3)` to `hide()` the unrequired ones. Try this:

```js
$('#id_show12').click(function() {
  $('.show12 li:gt(1)').hide();
})
$('#id_show34').click(function() {
  $('.show34 li').not(':eq(2), :eq(3)').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="show12">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="show34">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button id="id_show12">show only one/two</button>
<button id="id_show34">show only three/four</button>
```

Comment: Instead of `.hide().filter(...).show()` you can better use `.not(...).hide()` here. And I'm not sure why you've added the class in `.show34 li:eq(3)`. I'd write this as `$('.show34 li').not(':eq(2), :eq(3)').hide();`

Comment: thansk @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @Thomas You're right about using `not()` - updated. The class use was simply a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**edit button's id**

```
<button id="id_show12">show only one two li</button>
<button id="id_show34">show three four two li</button>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(function(){
  $('#id_show12').click(function(){
        $('.show12 li:nth-child(n+3)').css("display", "none");   
    })
  $('#id_show34').click(function(){
       $('.show34 li:nth-child(-n+2), .show34 li:nth-child(n+5)').css("display", "none");  
    })
})
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/renolawiwu/1/edit?html,js,output)